# Change of Primary Synonym: Axapta -> Microsoft-Dynamics-AX

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request, synonym-request

Please could we change the primary synonym `Axapta` to `Microsoft-Dynamics-AX`?
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/axapta/synonyms

**More Info**

`Axapta` was originally a product by `IBM` and `Damgaard Data`.
It was purchased by `Microsoft` who renamed it to `Dynamics AX`.
As such the current product name is `Microsoft Dynamics AX`, with the term `Axapta` dropping out of use.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_AX

Comment: [tag:microsoft-dynamics-ax] as a tag was used 6 times in the past 9 years (when it was created). [tag:axpata] clearly is the more used tag.